# How to make Vimperator's numbered links bigger? (hints)

Tags: vimperator

Is there any way to make Vimperator's hints (link numbers displayed after hitting the <kbd>f</kbd>/<kbd>F</kbd> key) slightly larger?

Answer (score 18):

I'm using [Pentadactyl](http://dactyl.sourceforge.net/pentadactyl/), which is a fork of Vimperator, but I think it's exactly the same on this particular issue.

Anyway, you can use the `:highlight` command (see `:help highlight`) to add any CSS to the Hint group, like this:

`:highlight Hint font-size:200%;color:white;background-color:red;padding:2px;`

(Or put the same in your .vimperatorrc to make it permanent.)

Change font-size:200%; to whatever you want, or add any other CSS you like. (Here's [a CSS tutorial at w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) if you want it.)

Answer (score 5):

In addition:

- to revert back to defaults: `:highlight clear Hint`
- to only change the font size: `:highlight Hint -append font-size:16px;`

  - Note `;` at the end
  - Note `-append`
  - Note case sensitivity
  - Note that, in contrast to: `font-size:200%`, this sets the size of the font to be *fixed*, regardless of what's the size of the text to be highlighted
- to verify that changes were made: `:highlight Hint` , optionally select the appropriate completion with Tab, triple mouse click on the Vimperator's command var, Ctrl+C