# How to change characters used for link hints in Firefox Vimperator?

Tags: firefox, characters, vimperator

Instead of *numbers* used for `link hints` in `Firefox` `Vimperator` addon, I would like to display *characters* like in `Vimium` in `Google Chrome`.

How can I change this configuration?

Comment: Note: You lose the feature to select a link by typing a part of it. Before switching, you might consider to keep the numbers.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `hintchars` variable determines which characters are used for hints. By default, it's set to `0123456789`, but you can change it to whatever characters you like. Enter this:

```
:set hintchars=hjklasdfgyuiopqwertnmzxcvb
```

The characters are used in the defined order.

See this question on changing the hint's appereance: [How to make Vimperator's numbered links bigger? (hints)](https://superuser.com/questions/230741/how-to-make-vimperators-numbered-links-bigger)

To make the settings permament, put the commands (without the colons) in your `.vimperatorrc` file, see `:help initialization`.

Comment: Can you add more information to this. Why is this a solution? What does it do?

Comment: Worked though ! ..... but I also don't like the red color ....... would you please tell me how to change the colors....thks.

Comment: Replace the `red` by another color you like. To learn more, read the CSS tutorial linked in the other answer.

Comment: Now it is `:set hintkeys=asdfg;lkjh`

Comment: @Deqing That doesn't seem to have changed. Should still be `hintchars`. Maybe you're using another version of vimperator, or maybe it is actually Pendactyl?